# mapping data member with diffrent name in @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Customer class:

```
public class Customer {
    private String custName;
    private String custFirstName;
    private String custMiddleName;
    private String custLastName;
}
```

JSP:

```
<form:input mandatory="true" id="CustNameTxt" path="custName"
            cssClass="txtfield controlWidth" readonly="false" />
```

if my path="cName"

```
<form:input mandatory="true" id="CustNameTxt" path="cName"
            cssClass="txtfield controlWidth" readonly="false" />
```

then how i'll map the cName parameter with my Customer class object in `spring`

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer1,
                                HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session)
```

Comment: No you cannot,

either you should have a `POJO` directly mapping to exact fields, which Spring binds it on its own or else send some json response and then parse at your end and save whatever format you have to.

Comment: @ankur-singhal can i take it using @PathVariable("cName") String custName or @RequestParam("cName") String custName??

Comment: yes using `RequestParam` will work for you, all the form elements are submitted in request params, unless we are setting explicitly in the url.

Comment: @ankur-singhal can i take it using @RequestParam("cName")  in the same code i can not do RND on the code so could u please tell me here am i getting cName in request param or not.

Comment: changing `path` alone will not help you, you need to provide name or id as `cName` to get it into request param

Comment: i've already given the id as CustNameTxt am i right please confirm post that i'll post one more comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83171/discussion-between-ankur-singhal-and-piyush-mittal).

Comment: Try adding name attribute as well, id i am not 100% sure, that you will be able to retrieve it in RequestParam